# centering block made of an image next to a paragraph

Tags: html, css, image, text, centering

it's my first question here, while i solved many problems in any area reading other's solutions, but this time i have no luck, i keep trying and googling.

I am working with something i'm not very skilled, CSS. I want to **center a box made of an image with a paragraph of text next to it (two rows of text - no more)**, the text is aligned to the left of the image.

|------------------------------------ NOW ------------------------------------|

```
|img|BIG TITLE
|img|smaller subtext
```

|----------------------------- <-- CENTERED----> -----------------------------|

```
                   |img|BIG TITLE
                   |img|smaller subtext
```

I tried to put everything in a div, but since the width of the DIV depends on the length of the text, and since it changes depending on the page's title, i can't set a fixed width.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="header">
        <p class="small">
<img class="ok" src="ok.png">
<span class="bigtitle">TITLE</span>
<br><span style="text-align:left">subtext</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.row .header {
width: 100%;
}

img.ok {
top: 15px;
}

p.small {
color: #000000;
font: bold 12px arial,helvetica,sanserif;
display: block;
}

span.bigtitle {
color: #679819;
text-transform:uppercase;
font: bold 42px arial,helvetica,sanserif;
}


    text-align: center;
```

Then i tried:

- putting everything in a paragraph and     text-align: center;
- setting Margin 0px auto to the paragraph;
- putting everything in a div and tried centering but i don't know its width
- googled and searched for solutions here...

Nothing works, i can't center the block, please help :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could float and relatively position the containers like this:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row { 
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    float: left;    
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    float: left;    
}
```

If you have more content in the container div than just this centered bit, you might wrap the centered bit in another div and move the overflow: hidden rule out of .container and to that div instead.

Comment: thanks it really helped! The only thing is that subtext gets centered as well!! But it would be easier for me to fix this now that the rest is centered! thanks a lot for the fast reply